# Passing data dynamically to template in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to use same template with different data set and I am not sure how to do that.

My template looks like:

```
<template name="eventsList">
  <div class="event">
        {{#each events}}
          {{> eventItem}}
        {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

and i want to use it something like:

```
<template name="dashboard">
<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="all-events">
            {{>eventsList allEvents}}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="my-events">
            {{>eventsList registeredEvents}}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="archived-events">
            {{>eventsList archivedEvents}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now all the parameters i.e. allEvents, registeredEvents and archivedEvents are fetched from same mongo db collection but selection criteria is different and I am fetching them like:

```
Template.eventsDashboard.allEvents = function() {
    return Events.find({scheduleDate: {$gte: new Date()}}, {sort: {scheduleDate: 1}});
}

Template.eventsDashboard.registeredEvents = function() {
    return Events.find({registeredUsers: Meteor.userId()}, {sort: {scheduleDate: 1}});
}

Template.eventsDashboard.archivedEvents = function() {
   return Events.find({scheduleDate: {$lt: new Date()}}, {sort: {scheduleDate: 1}});
}
```

But I get an error in js console which says "**Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined**". If i define helper method for eventslist like below:

```
Template.eventsList.helpers({
    events: function() {
        return Events.find({scheduleDate: {$gte: new Date()}}, {sort: {scheduleDate:     1}});
    }
});
```

then error goes away but in all three tabs of all events, registered events and archived events whatever returned by eventsList helper is displayed.

Please let me know what is missing in above code.

Thanks,
Aashu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `{{#each events}}` to `{{#each this}}` - the template is looking for a field on its data object (or a helper) called `events`, but its actually seeing a cursor that doesn't have an `events` field. The keyword `this` will make it just use its data object (the cursor) for the `#each` block.